# How to catch exception from constructor without handling entire the function?

Tags: c++, constructor, try-catch, c++17

*This question is all about just finding any solution that doesn't carry too much boilerplate code - while this could generate some opinion based solutions - Im really just looking for any solution (wihtout too much boilerplate code)*

The following is causing me a bit of headache  - while I can easily fix this, I would like to avoid too much boilerplate code. The following is not legal [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) but shows intent.

```
char* newBuffer(const char* filename)
{
    auto fm = try { //<--try is not legal here
        boost::interprocess::file_mapping(filename, boost::interprocess::read_only);
    }
    catch (boost::interprocess::interprocess__exception& e) {
        //report error
        return nullptr;//<--this actually makes matters worse since now we cannot just simply wrap in a simpel lambda or function..
    }
    //rest of function ...
}
```

[snippet on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Ug8quN)

I could just move the try at the beginning of the function but that would mean to just `try` the entire function (bad practice) instead of just `try`'ing `file_mapping` constructor.
How would you solve this conundrum and avoid try-block around the entire function ? less boilerplate code is preferred better.

**Any answer should also address the issue with returning of nullptr in case of failure.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you'd declare the variable outside the try block:

```
boost::interprocess::file_mapping fm;
try {
  fm = boost::interprocess::file_mapping(filename, boost::interprocess::read_only);
} catch (boost::interprocess::interprocess__exception& e) {
// Handle error  
  return nullptr;

}
```

This requires the type to be movable at least.

You could return it from a lambda, but then you'd have to return a `std::optional` or similar to indicate the error case, or throw another exception.

Comment: Works in this particular (and many others, to be honest) case but not a general solution because has some drawbacks: (1) require an assignment operator for the object, not ever available (2) use construction and assignment instead construction only so (2a) can be inefficient and (2b) doesn't works at all if you want initialize a constant object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a directly invoked lambda, like so:

```
auto fm = [&] { try {      
        return boost::interprocess::file_mapping(filename, boost::interprocess::read_only);
    } catch (const boost::interprocess::interprocess__exception& e) {
    //report error
    } }();
// Rest of function
```

Comment: What would you return from the lambda in case of a catch?

Comment: @rustyx - good point. Probably a `std::optional` in both cases.

Comment: And how would you return nullptr in case of failure ?

Answer (score 1):

This is very much similar to [Jesper Juhl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58472212/2323908) and [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58472180/how-to-catch-exception-from-constructor-without-handling-entire-the-function#comment103277921_58472212), but I have clarified how to deal with returning a nullptr should the constructor throw.

```cpp
char* newBuffer(const char* filename)
{
    auto fm_opt = [&]{
        try {
            return std::make_optional(boost::interprocess::file_mapping(filename, boost::interprocess::read_only));
        }
        catch (boost::interprocess::interprocess__exception& e) {
            //report error
            return std::nullopt;
        }
    }();

    if(!fm_opt.has_value()) return nullptr;

    //rest of function ...
}
```

Comment: Well, this can be simplied indeed and it's  what Im trying to avoid - too much 'boilerplate' code (before this was just a single line of code - if you disregard the try-catch).

Comment: If using an optional anyway - i don't need the extra lambda.

Comment: @DavisHerring `nullptr` is returned from the outer function. `std::nullopt` is returned from the lambda.

Comment: @JoakimThorén: Right—I somehow ignored the outer `return` entirely, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Controlling constructor invocation timing is a feature of `std::optional` (beyond the obvious “represent a lack of object”):

```
char* newBuffer(const char *f) {
  std::optional<boost::interprocess::file_mapping> fm0;
  try {
    fm0.emplace(f,boost::interprocess::read_only);
  }
  catch (boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception& e) {
    //report error
    return nullptr;
  }

  auto &fm=*fm0;
  // …
}
```

There is the minor overhead involved of storing the “non-empty” state of the `optional`, but that’s probably of no concern.